# Construct a strictly decreasing sequence of closed sets

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff space with infinitely many points, then how to construct a strictly decreasing (infinite) sequence of closed subsets of $X$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $A_1$ be an infinite closed subset of $X$.

For two distinct elements  $a$ and $b$ of $A_1$ , find disjoint open sets containing $a$ and $b$ respectively. The collection of all such sets is an open cover of the compact set $A_1$ and thus has a finite subcover.

One element, $E$, from this finite subcover is open, contains infinitely many elements of $A_1$, but the closure of $E\cap A_1$ is not all of $A_1$.

Let $A_2$ be the closure of $E\cap A_1$.

Continue ...

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Every infinite Hausdorff space includes a (countably) infinite discrete subspace (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/601210/8348)) $A$.  Since $A$ is discrete, it follows that $x \notin \overline{ A \setminus \{ x \} }$ for all $x \in A$.  Now expand on this to construct a strictly decreasing sequence of closed subsets of $X$.

Comment: I don't think it includes a (countably) infinite discrete subspace, since $X$ is compact, any infinite subset has a limit point hence cannot be discrete.

Comment: @Lao-tzu: I mean discrete as a subspace.  Consider $[0,1]$ and the subset $A = \{ \frac{1}{n} :  \geq 1 \}$. As a subspace of $[0,1]$ $A$ is discrete, even though it has a limit point.  (It is just discrete, not _closed_ discrete.)

Comment: OK, thank you, I'll think a little.