# Finite topological space

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a *Hausdorff* topological space such that every closed subset has finitely many connected component. How can I verify that $X$ is finite?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: every infinite Hausdorff space has an infinite discrete (in itself) subset.

(E.g. see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/601210/4280))

The cofinite topology on $\mathbb{N}$ shows that being $T_1$ is not enough.

Comment: I don't understand how this answers the Q. Maybe I'm not seeing something obvious.

Comment: For that infinite discrete subset, ask yourself: what are its components? And those of its closure?

Comment: The Q is about components of closed subsets

Comment: Consider the closure.

Comment: yes ok it's obvious