# Finite topological space

Tags: algebraic-topology, geometric-topology, general-topology

At [Finite topological space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1528995/finite-topological-space) the user asked "Let $X$ be a *Hausdorff* topological space such that every closed subset has finitely many connected component. How can I verify that $X$ is finite?" I want to know is this true if every **proper** closed subset has finitely many connected component?

Answer (score 1):

The same answer works, essentially. Suppose $X$ is infinite and Hausdorff. Then $X$ has a discrete (in itself) infinite subspace $S$. Pick $p \in S$. Then $\overline{S\setminus\{p\}}$ is proper (as $p$ is not in the closure of $S\setminus \{p\}$), closed, and has all points of $S \setminus \{p\}$ as components so has infinitely many components (they're still isolated points, so cannot be in a strictly larger connected subset), contrary to assumption. So $X$ is finite.

Comment: How do you find $S$ to begin with?

Comment: Same reference as my original answer: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/533051/4280

Comment: Thanks!  It makes perfect sense now.