# Compact spaces in which any closed set can be partitioned into finitely many closed sets whose clopen subsets extend to the whole space

Tags: general-topology, compactness, connectedness

Let $X $ be a compact topological space (not necessarilly Hausdorff). I am looking for a charactrization for the following property:

Property: If $C $ is a closed subset of $X $, then there are pairwise disjoint closed subsets $C_1$,...,$C_n $ of $X $ such that $C=C_1\cup\dots\cup C_n $, and each $C_i $  has the property that if $A $  is a clopen subest of $C_i $, then there exists a clopen subset $B $ of $X $  with $A=C_i\cap B$?

Any comment is very welcome.

Comment: The spaces that every closed subset has finitely many connected components are example of such spaces.

Comment: Well, in the case that $X$ is Hausdorff, this is equivalent to total disconnectedness.

Comment: By “clopen subset of $C_i$”, you surely mean “subset clopen w.r.t. the subspace topology of $C_i$”?

Comment: @Luke, yes in the subspace topology.

Comment: @Eric Wofsey, Can you provide a proof for your comment.

Comment: @Andy.G A pair of points is a closed set, and your definition produces a clopen set containing one of those points and not the other. This is the definition of totally disconnected.

Comment: @Mike Miller, Why is a pair of points closed and why is the convers true?

Comment: Neither direction is obvious; I'm writing an answer elaborating now.

Comment: @MikeMiller: No, because you could take $C_1$ and $C_2$ to be the two singletons.  Note that the $C_i$ do not need to be clopen in $X$.

Comment: @EricWofsey Of course. Thanks for correcting that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see any reason to believe there is a simpler necessary and sufficient condition in general.  When $X$ is Hausdorff there is one, though: your condition is equivalent to $X$ being totally disconnected.

To prove this, first suppose $X$ is compact Hausdorff and totally disconnected.  Then clopen sets separate points of $X$ (see [Any two points in a Stone space can be disconnected by clopen sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11412/any-two-points-in-a-stone-space-can-be-disconnected-by-clopen-sets)).  It follows by compactness that clopen sets also separate closed sets (the proof is the same as the proof that a compact Hausdorff space is normal, just using clopen sets instead of open sets everywhere).  So in particular, if $C\subseteq X$ is closed and $A$ is clopen in $C$, then $A$ and $C\setminus A$ can be separated by clopen subsets of $X$ (since they are disjoint and closed in $X$).  This means that your condition holds, with $n=1$.

Conversely, suppose $X$ is compact Hausdorff and not totally disconnected.  Your property is inherited by closed subspaces, so we may replace $X$ with one of its nontrivial connected components.  So, we assume $X$ is compact Hausdorff and connected and has more than one point, and must show it does not satisfy your condition.

To prove this, pick an infinite discrete subset $D\subset X$ (see [Every infinite Hausdorff space has an infinite discrete subspace](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/533051/every-infinite-hausdorff-space-has-an-infinite-discrete-subspace)) and consider $C=\overline{D}$.  Suppose a decomposition $C=C_1\cup\dots\cup C_n$ with your property existed.  Note that each point of $D$ is isolated in $C$, and some $C_i$ must contain infinitely many points of $D$.  In particular, some $C_i$ must be disconnected, so there is a nontrivial clopen subset $A\subset C_i$.  But $X$ is connected, so it has no nontrivial clopen subsets, and so $A$ cannot be $B\cap C_i$ for any clopen $B\subseteq X$.

---

Of course, total disconnectedness is not necessary in the non-Hausdorff case (I don't know whether it is sufficient).  Besides trivial examples like the indiscrete topology, there is also the cofinite topology on any set.  More generally, as Es.Ro commented, a sufficient condition is that every closed subset of $X$ has only finitely many connected components, since then you can take the connected components as the $C_i$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Can we find a special family $F $  of closed subsets of $X $ (in non Hausdorff case)  such that if each element of $F $ has a partition with the stated property, then all close subsets of $X $ have a partition with the stated property?